# Delphi XE Unicode dealing with nchar(1) fields

Tags: sql-server, delphi, unicode, delphi-xe, tadodataset

I'm using a dbGo `TADODataset` in Delphi XE to read data from a SQL Server 2008 table. All the string fields are nvarchar or nchar.

The nvarchar fields map to `TWideStringField` with no problems.

The problem is with an `nchar(1)` field, this maps to a `TStringField` fine but not to a `TWideStringField` - when I configure the field to be `TWideStringField` I get the error:

> Type mismatch for field `'foobar'`, expecting: `WideString` actual: `FixedChar`

The problem in using a `TStringField` is that it is UTF8 and we want to make our application fully unicode compliant.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. That field is used for what, exactly?

In most db designs I've seen, an (n)Char(1) field are normally used for
one-letter flags - which can be easily represented in an ASCII char.

I would recomend change the type of the column to CHAR(1), if that's the
case.